# Snapshot of AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer

Tags: ios

I have some video displaying on an AVsampleBufferDisplayLayer and would like to capture this image and save it to the photo album. As AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer inherits from CALayer I thought it would be acceptable to use this in renderInContext.

```
[targetView.layer addSublayer:avLayer];


UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetView.bounds.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[avLayer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                   self,
                                   @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                   NULL);
```

but this results in a blank white image being saved into the photo album.
Any thoughts on where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I have no suggestions on how to make the current approach you're taking work, but the right way to do this is not use AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer at all and instead use VideoToolbox's VTDecompressionSession to have the H.264 frames decoded and handed back to you as CVPixelBuffers in a callback, which you can then convert and save to disk.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for a week or so but ended up fixing this by switching from AVSampleDisplayLayer to VTDecompressionSession.  In the VTDecompression didDecompress callback method, I send the decompressed image (CVImageBufferRef) into the following method to get a screenshot of the video stream and turn it into a UIImage.

```
-(void) screenshotOfVideoStream:(CVImageBufferRef)imageBuffer
{
    CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:imageBuffer];
    CIContext *temporaryContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef videoImage = [temporaryContext
                             createCGImage:ciImage
                             fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 
                             CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer), 
                             CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer))];

    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:videoImage];
    [self doSomethingWithOurUIImage:image];
    CGImageRelease(videoImage);
}
```

I have no idea why VTD would support screenshots but AVSampleLayer wouldn't.  Seems like it might be a bug/error on Apple's part??

Comment: How do you send the CVImageBufferRef to an objective C function from a C style function when you have no access to 'self' ?

Comment: Also when using VTDecompression Session for playback, how do you 'add' the P frames to the iFrames? Do you use layering and paste the layer onto the image?

Comment: In reference to your first question, the VTDecomp callback should look something like this "void decompressionSessionDecodeFrameCallback( void *decompressionOutputRefCon, void *sourceFrameRefCon, OSStatus status, VTDecodeInfoFlags infoFlags, CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer, CMTime presentationTimeStamp, CMTime presentationDuration)" 

To access self, cast decompressionOutputRefCon like so:
    "THISCLASSNAME *streamManager = (__bridge THISCLASSNAME *)decompressionOutputRefCon;"

Then you can call the method like this: "[streamManager screenshotOfVideoStream:imageBuffer];"

Comment: It's hard to answer your second question because it all depends on how you are getting your video stream, but you can't do what you suggested exactly.  I was receiving the raw H.264 video data and I split it up into its separate NALUs.  I pulled out the SPS and PPS NALUs and took the parameters from them to initialize the VTDecompressionSession.  Then I took the IFrame and PFrame NALUs, packaged them into CMBlockBuffers, then into CMSampleBuffers which I passed into the method “VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame”.  There are some other examples of this online that go into more detail.

Comment: Ah ok, so the VTDecompressionsessionDecodeFrame takes care of the final image you just feed it the NALUS as you receive them. Thanks for response