# Video stream in AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer doesn't show up in screenshot

Tags: ios, ios8, uiimage, screenshot, cmsamplebufferref

I've been using the new Video Toolbox methods to take an H.264 video stream and display it in a view controller using `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer`.  This all works as intended and the stream looks great.  **However, when I try to take a screenshot of the entire view, the contents of the `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer` (i.e. the decompressed video stream) do not show up in the snapshot.**  The snapshot shows all other UI buttons/labels/etc. but the screenshot only shows the background color of the `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer` (which I had set to bright blue) and not the live video feed.

In the method below (inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454356/uiimage-from-calayer-iphone-sdk)) I take the `SampleBuffer` from my stream and queue it to be displayed on the `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer`.  Then I call my method *imageFromLayer:* to get the snapshot as a `UIImage`.  (I then either display that UIImage in the *UIImageView imageDisplay*, or I save it to the device's local camera roll to verify what the `UIImage` looks like.  Both methods yield the same result.)

```
-(void) h264VideoFrame:(CMSampleBufferRef)sample
{
    [self.AVSampleDisplayLayer enqueueSampleBuffer:sample];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        UIImage* snapshot = [self imageFromLayer:self.AVSampleDisplayLayer];
        [self.imageDisplay setImage:snapshot];
    });
}
```

Here I simply take the contents of the `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer` and attempt to convert it to a `UIImage`.  If I pass the entire screen into this method as the layer, all other UI elements like labels/buttons/images will show up except for the `AVDisplayLayer`.  If I pass in just the `AVDisplayLayer`, I get a solid blue image (since the background color is blue).

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromLayer:(CALayer *)layer
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions([layer frame].size, YES, 1.0);

    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    //UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputImage, self, nil, nil);

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return outputImage;
}
```

I've tried using `UIImage snapshot = [self imageFromLayer: self.AVSampleDisplayLayer.presentationLayer];`  and `.modelLayer`, but that didn't help.  I've tried queueing the samplebuffer and waiting before taking a snapshot, I've tried messing with the opacity and xPosition of the `AVDisplayLayer`...  I've even tried setting different values for the `CMTimebase` of the `AVDisplayLayer`.  Any hints are appreciated!

Also according to [this post](http://www.tagwith.com/question_176930_renderincontext-not-working-in-ios-8), and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162479/snapshot-of-avsamplebufferdisplaylayer) other people are having similar troubles with snapshots in iOS 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by switching from `AVSampleDisplayLayer` to `VTDecompressionSession`.  In the `VTDecompression didDecompress` callback method, I send the decompressed image (`CVImageBufferRef`) into the following method to get a screenshot of the video stream and turn it into a `UIImage`.

```
-(void) screenshotOfVideoStream:(CVImageBufferRef)imageBuffer
{
    CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:imageBuffer];
    CIContext *temporaryContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef videoImage = [temporaryContext
                             createCGImage:ciImage
                             fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 
                             CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer), 
                             CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer))];

    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:videoImage];
    [self doSomethingWithOurUIImage:image];
    CGImageRelease(videoImage);
}
```

Comment: Could you please share example of VTDecompressionSession to take screenshot..I am using same AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer and screenshot feature not woking on device.

Comment: It was a long time ago so I dont have the code anymore unfortunately.  All I remember is using the `screenshotOfVideoStream` method (above) in the `VTDecompression::didDecompress` callback.  Sorry I can't be of more help.